# how to allow remote access to postgresql 11?

Tags: postgresql

how to allow remote access to postgresql 11 (CentOS 7)?

I tried below:

```
/var/lib/pgsql/data

== postgresql.conf ==

listen_addresses = '*'

== pg_hba.conf ==
host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0                       md5
local   all     all     trust
host    all     all     0.0.0.0/0       trust
```

I also allowed port 5432 in firewalld and iptables

but still unable to access it from my notebook (10.100.100.188)..

anybody has experienced on this?

thanks a lot in advance

Regards
Don

Comment: have you restarted postgres after the modifications?

Comment: Try asking at https://dba.stackexchange.com/. They might be able provide at better answer. This section is more related to programming questions. HTH.

Comment: Can you get a network connection? You can test with anything that establishes a TCP connection, e.g. `wget http://server.domain.com:5432`. If that gets connected (and then fails) the network connection is ok, and you should consult the PostgreSQL log. If the connection attempt fails on the TCP level (times out or is refused), you have a network problem unrelated to PostgreSQL.

Comment: yes, I able to ping to the server and noted, will go to dba.stackexchange.com .. thanks a lot